# How to run and debug client-server project in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

There are three classes: Server, Client, Test. I need to run server which waits for client and process it's commands. While trying to run two classes within Test it ends up in server's while (wait cycle for client connection on a socket):

```
class Test{
    new Server();
    new Client();
}
```

How to run and debug this kind of application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just create two `Threads` like this:

```
Thread serverThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    new Server();
  }
});
Thread clientThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    new Client();
  }
});
serverThread.start();
clientThread.start();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can run two processes in Eclipse simultaneously.
Run the Server in "debug" and run Test in "debug", the processes will each stop in the designated breakpoints. As far as I understand Test invokes Client commands, right?
You don't need to run both in the same process.

Answer (score 1):

You need to start another thread for your server loop, this is usually done in the setup phase of a test.

Assuming you're using JUnit 4.

```
class Test {
    @BeforeClass
    public static void setup() {
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                new Server();
            }
        }.start();
    }
    @AfterClass
    public static void teardown() {
        // stop the server (somehow)
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        new Client();
    }
}
```